# jquery object literal function / closure - missing something obvious?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

How can I get this to work? seems to be a trivial mistake Im not seeing

```
   (function($){
      $.myNamespace = {
        num:0,
        incNum: function(){
                  return num++;},
        decNum: function(){
                  return num--;},
        getNum: function(){
                return num;
                }
      };
    })(jQuery);
```

calling $.myNamespace.incNum gives a 'ReferenceError: num is not defined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function ($) {
    $.myNamespace = {
        num: 0,
        incNum: function () {
            return this.num++;
        },
        decNum: function () {
            return this.num--;
        },
        getNum: function () {
            return this.num;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit all of the return statements to reference the object.

```
 return this.num++;
```

So your code will look like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.myNamespace = {
        num: 0,
        incNum: function () {
            return this.num++;
        },
        decNum: function () {
            return this.num--;
        },
        getNum: function () {
            return this.num;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

`num` isn't part of the function's scope; JavaScript has no concept of namespaces. Instead, you should access `num` as `$.myNamespace.num` or `this.num` (though I don't recommend that - `this` can be bound to arbitrary objects.)

Answer (score 0):

'num' is inside your parent class 'myNamespace'...and if you want to access it form the children methods of this class then as @Kieran said you need to use the this keyword, i.e this.num++